# Does memcache get refreshes the expriry time key

Tags: caching, memcached

Recently while using memcache for one of the project, I observed the key gets expired even if the key was being retrieved continuously. I am eager to know if this is a default behavior of memcache. Can we override this behaviors to refresh the key's periodically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way memcache will refresh the time on get. So to reset the time for memcache, it should be again set into the server. That way the timeout value will reset to zero.

Answer (score -1):

There should be a command in the latest memcached call gat (get and touch). You can use that command in order to refresh the expiration time when getting a key. Just doing a normal get will not cause the expiration time to be updated.

Comment: I am using google ssm client for memcached server. Seems it doesn't have the api for gat. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: I tried the gat command on memcahe1.4.15 version. It didn't work. Am I missing something?